# Google App Script breaking singular element into 1D array with several elements

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I've created a custom script in GAS (for Google Sheets) so I could join several data sources into one unique display. I added a .splice in the middle so I could cut out all null elements inside the arrays (which meant removing blank rows in the return array).

Here is it how the code goes:

```
function COMPILER(){

var i;
var c;
var r;
var display = [];

for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
for (c = 0; c < arguments[i].length;c++) {

display.push(arguments[i][c]);

};};

for (r = display.length-1; r >= 0; r--) {

if (display[r][1]==""){

display.splice(r, 1)

};};

return display

};
```

The code works fine with 2+D arrays and with 1D arrays that have 2+ elements; but when its working with 1D arrays that have only one element, it unintendedly breaks down the strings into several elements.

Instead of returning:

ar1
ar2

It returns

a
r
1
a
r
2

How could I solve this?

Comment: display.push(arguments[i]) or display.push([arguments[i]]) ... it depends upon what you want.

Comment: Can you provide sample function calls? I am not sure what you mean by 2D array vs 1D array. You're just going through `arguments` which is an array for all of the arguments. There may be 1 argument, 2 arguments, or 100 arguments. How is the `COMPILER` function being called?

Comment: Thank you about the arrays, changed the questions already.

Comment: My data is mostly 2D arrays (columns and rows in Google Sheets) filled with strings. The `COMPILER` function should do 4 things: first it should join the data in every irregular array inside `arguments` into one unique regular array that has the combined number of rows ([i]) and the maximum number of columns ([C]). Then, it tests every row for empty elements and removes the ones that are. And finally, it displays the resulting array into one unique and organized cartesian plan inside the sheet in which the formula has been called (as "`=COMPILER(Argument1'A:F;Argument2'R2:T2;etc)`").

Comment: My problem is that, when any argument inside `arguments` is a 1D array with only one element inside, the formula breaks down the string into several elements, instead of considering it element with a string inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think/assume this is what you're trying to do:

```
function COMPILER()
{
    var display = [];

    for(var i = 0, numArguments = arguments.length; i < numArguments; ++i)
    {
        //console.log([i, arguments[i], Array.isArray(arguments[i])]);
        if(Array.isArray(arguments[i]))
        {
            for(var j = 0, len = arguments[i].length; j < len; ++j)
            {
                if(arguments[i][j] != "")
                {
                    display.push(arguments[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(arguments[i] != "")
        {
            display.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }

    return display;
}
```

I can't confirm/test cause I don't know how you're calling `COMPILER`.

Comment: I couldn't find any references to the .isArray method in Google App Script manifest, and it doesn't seem to exist as a built-in method (believe me, I tried). If not for that, your solution would work thought.

Comment: It is a JavaScript function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: If it does not work in your code, you can add it. Check the Polyfill section of the Mozilla link I pasted.

Comment: I didn't actually use your code because I'm working with Databases and in doing so I would loose the original positioning of the elements inside `arguments`, but your solve was spot on! I added the `.isArray` method as suggested and it worked as a charm. Thanks!